# Universal Image Loader: stop populating ListView images on fragment change

Tags: android, image, listview, android-fragments, universal-image-loader

I am using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load images to `ListView` items (with custom `Adapter`, in `getView()` method). I was wondering how to force the library to stop loading images when I change fragment holding the `ListView` to another one. I tried following solutions but non of them worked:

1. call `stop()` on imageLoader instance in fragment's onDestroy(). Unfortunately this also stops loading images on the fragment I am switching to.
2. call `clear()` on listView or on underlying `Adapter`, again in fragment's `onDestroy()`. This has no effect.

What I am trying to prevent is loading images for the fragment that is no longer visible. Is there any clever way to achieve this? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: ImageLoader.getInstance().destroy(); did you try destroying the instance altogether ? and get new instance in the fragment you are moving to ??

Comment: I think what happens is that new Fragment gets instantiated before old one gets destroyed. Both fragments have the same instance of ImageLoader (obtained by ImageLoader.getInstance()) so when I call .destroy() on the instance, it has effect on the new Fragment as well.